# Adding lettuce to an existing django project throws 'model already registered'

Tags: django, lettuce

I am trying to add Lettuce to an existing **Django project**.  With a very simple features directory configured I keep getting `django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered`: The model Family is already registered.  I checked for differing imports (e.g. `import .models` vs `import reg.models`), duplicate imports, and errant applications that might be re-importing my admin.py to no avail.  The error seems to be coming from lettuce trying to reload a module. I'm not sure why it would want to do that.  Traceback is below.

```
(dwcoop)s001 cro-mbp[126]% DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.testing django-admin.py harvest reg
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Django's builtin server is running at 0.0.0.0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cro/src/ve/dwcoop/lib/python2.7/site- packages/lettuce/django/management/commands/harvest.py", line 167, in handle
    result = runner.run()
  File "/Users/cro/src/ve/dwcoop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lettuce/__init__.py", line 137, in run
    self.loader.find_and_load_step_definitions()
  File "/Users/cro/src/ve/dwcoop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lettuce/fs.py", line 60, in find_and_load_step_definitions
    reload(module)  # always take fresh meat :)
  File "/Users/cro/src/ve/dwcoop/web/web/reg/admin.py", line 60, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Family, FamilyAdmin)
  File "/Users/cro/src/ve/dwcoop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 83, in register
    raise AlreadyRegistered('The model %s is already registered' % model.__name__)
AlreadyRegistered: The model Family is already registered
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue coming from a cucumber background expecting to start by running "harvest" and then writing my first feature file. But I was faced with that error. Apparently if you don't have a feature folder inside the apps you're running harvest against (defined by LETTUCE_APPS inside settings.py) and at least one step definition file (.py) inside it. It looks like if it doesn't land upon features in the default locations it starts an exhaustive search that reloads the module and thus brings about the admin reload fail.

Comment: In my case I had a features folder but I didn't have any *steps.py file in it (only the *.feature file) and got the same error. Once I created an empty *steps.py file the error went away and harvest printed out the steps skeleton.

Comment: This is such a misleading error message. I have already encountered it two times and had to google for this answer each time

Answer (score 0):

When you specify your application to run features for above, you need to specify the application you are running against.  That can be done one of several ways.

First off, it doesn't work to specify the app directly as above like you would do with standard tests.

1. You can add the app flag to the command. [Documented here.](http://lettuce.it/recipes/django-lxml.html#lettuce-running-tests-from-just-certain-apps)
   Example: ./manage.py harvest -apps=my_app,my_app2
2. You can specify the direct path to your features directory
   Example: ./manage.py harvest my_app/features
3. You can leave off the app and specify which apps to test in your settings.py file with:
   LETTUCE_APPS = (
       'my_app',
       'my_app2',
   )

Comment: It appears to still throw this error for me when following your suggestions.